# How to use SOAP/WSDL in PHP 4?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, google-ads-api

More specifically I'm trying to make the google adwords API work using PHP 4. What are my options? Any links to a class I could use, sample code, etc would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had no problems with [NuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/)

And here is an example of using [NuSOAP with the Google API](http://www.useseo.com/google-api.php)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [wsdl2php](http://www.urdalen.no/wsdl2php/index.php) to create php proxy from wsdl file. afterwards you can use the generated proxy to send and recieve information from the webservice.